# MySQL running directly but syntax error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

EDIT: I see the problem is with multiple queries in PHP, so what workout is there for codeigntier? Do I have to use the mysqli functions them selves or can I use the built in Codeigniter DB classes?

I have a query that runs fine when I paste it into PHPMyAdmin, but when I run it in codeigniter it causes a syntax error, can anyone provide assistance?

Here is the SQL

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(user_fields_to_users.map_field_id=''',field_id,''',user_fields_to_users.map_data,NULL)) AS ', field_name)) INTO @sql

FROM user_custom_fields;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT *
                    ,', @sql, '
                    FROM user_accounts  LEFT JOIN user_fields_to_users ON
                    user_accounts.user_id = user_fields_to_users.map_user_id
          GROUP BY user_accounts.user_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

I am using `mysqli` with codeigniters `$this->db->query();`

The error I am getting is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(user_fields_t' at line 3
```

Comment: Try running `SET @sql = NULL;` as a separate query

Comment: Why single quote before `MAX` ?

Comment: My boss wrote it so I'm not sure, I'll ask

Comment: @ajtrichards It seems to get to line 8 when I do that, stops at the next SET command

Comment: I see this is a multiple queries problem...

Comment: @Alexander The single quote is to prevent execution of the statment until later when '@sql' is called

Comment: @Adam well, it's preventing it just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was multiple query's, here is the code I used

```
$sql = "
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(user_fields_to_users.map_field_id=''',field_id,''',user_fields_to_users.map_data,NULL)) AS ', field_name)) INTO @sql
FROM user_custom_fields;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT *
                    ,', @sql, '
                    FROM user_accounts  LEFT JOIN user_fields_to_users ON
                    user_accounts.user_id = user_fields_to_users.map_user_id
          GROUP BY user_accounts.user_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
";
if ($this->db->conn_id->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        if ($result = $this->db->conn_id->store_result()) {
            $this->selection_total_results = $result->num_rows;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $result_data[] = $row;
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    } while ($this->db->conn_id->next_result());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
'MAX(IF(user_fields_to_users.map_field_id
```

to

```
MAX(IF('user_fields_to_users.map_field_id
```